# UIPicker with object and keys using JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uipickerview

I am a bit stuck with UIpicker. here is my JSON data :

```
{
    "contact_id": [
        "455",
        "464"
    ],
    "contact_name": [
        "Administrator",
        "Main contact"
    ]
}
```

I stored the data into an NSdictionary , then after converting to the object, I created an NSarray to store the contact. in my Viewcontroller.m I have:
UIPicker with object and keys using JSON

```
// Creating an URL object
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://web.com/json.php"];    
//Creating the data object that will hold the content of the URL
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
contactlist = [result objectForKey:@"contact_name"];
```

I am able to display the contact value to the dropdown using contactlist. here are my other delegates

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
         return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        return [contactlist count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
         return [contactlist objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
contactTextField.text = (NSString *)[contactlist objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

I would like to send a JSON post request the corresponding id of the contact selected.

for example if you select contact_name `Administrator`, I would like to get its contact_id `455`
I created a method

```
- (IBAction)SendMessage:(id)sender ;
```

that creates the JSON data before sending it to my server side script, this is where I need to pass the id  not the contact name

```
// NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"603",  @"contact",nil];
```

I created this array in attempt to solve the problem but could not get it to work.

```
contactid = [result objectForKey:@"contact_id"];
```

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are trying to achieve here? What do you mean with "I would like to send in my JSON post request the corresponding id of the contact selected." You have maybe an example of what you want to achieve the JSON body example?

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: Still unclear for me do you have trouble getting the JSON formatted correctly or getting the contact_id from the from the method - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
contactTextField.text = (NSString *)[contactlist objectAtIndex:row]; ?

Comment: Its clear : I get the JSON and its valid. I am able to populate the picker with the contact_name value. Now I need to get the contact_ID because thats all my server cares about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK think I know understand you're question. There are several of solutions probably for this. But I will pass one that just got into me.

If id's array has the same order as the names just create a new array

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSArray* ids = (NSArray*)[result objectForKey:@"contact_id"];
```

And then in the method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component{}
```

Do the following to get the corresponding id:

```
NSString *idSentToServer = (NSString *)[ids objectAtIndex:row];
```

Answer (score 0):

I do understand it may be possible the way the JSON defined in your case as such.
Should your JSON data return an array of JSON objects?

Like following:

```
[{"contact_id":"455","contact_name":"Administrator"},{"contact_id":"464","contact_name":"Main contact"}]
```

Comment: are you asking me a question ? or you suggesting me to reformatt my JSON ?

Comment: anyhow your json is valid it interprets to me an object with a collection of ids and a collection of names.

Comment: I am also open to suggestion, do you think your format is easier to work with?

Comment: sorry got busy and was away. yes I think so the original code you posted might have worked if json was formatted as a json array with two objects which is provided in my comments